# Run ansible on specific hosts group

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I am trying to run ansible with the following command,

```
ansible-playbook provision.yml -l webserver
```

And my hosts file contains the following host groups,

```
[webclient]
172.29.4.75
[webserver]
172.29.4.76
```

My provision.yml also contains 2 hosts as below,

```
- hosts: webclient
  user: centos
  roles: 
   - nginx
   - nvm
- hosts: webserver
  user: centos
  roles: 
   - tomcat
```

My issue here is even thought I use "-l webserver" roles specified for webclient also runs in webclient hosts. How can I control it to run only specific host groups?

Comment: Your command should return an error that no group matches the limit.. The problem is that you didn't copy the content of the question from your real files and thus posted a fictional story instead of a verifiable example.

Comment: Yes as the yml file was big, I have just minimised it. corrected webserver in hosts file also now in question. My issue is -l options is not working properly for specific host groups

Comment: Nope, the inventory file file is not big, it contains four lines and with this file the command runs the playbook correctly on a single remaining group. Of course not the playbook you posted, because it was too much trouble for you to use a single `debug` task instead of roles. So it was better to put that burden on whoever reads the question.

Answer (score 2):

> My issue here is even thought I use "-l webserver" roles specified for webclient also runs in webclient hosts. How can I control it to run only specific host groups?

This usually means that you have same host under `webserver` and `webclient` groups.

Passing `-l webserver` tells Ansible to use all **host** from inventory, that are under `webserver` group.
When Ansible starts this play `- hosts: webclient`, it searches for matches in inventory and then reduce the match with hosts from `limit`  argument. So if you have some host that is both under `webserver` and `webclient`, Ansible will execute tasks from `webclient` play for them.

Comment: so how can I run roles which are specific to only " hosts: webserver" in my "provision.yml" specified above

Comment: Please see [best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#top-level-playbooks-are-separated-by-role). You should separate playbooks into different files and include them in your top level playbook.