# ansible returns incorrect vars when using dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

tested on: ansible 2.2.0.0, 2.2.1.0 & 2.1.4.0

I have a inventory script that returns this json when run (minimized for example's sake):

```
{
  "componentA-service_ci": {
    "hosts": [
      "host1.example.com",
      "host2.example.com"
    ],
    "vars": {
      "httpport": "8100",
      "nginxpool": "componentA_pool"
    }
  },
  "componentB-service_ci": {
    "hosts": [
      "host1.example.com",
      "host3.example.com"
    ],
    "vars": {
      "httpport": "9999",
      "nginxpool": "componentB_pool"
    }
  }
}
```

The playbook I'm writing are for deploying applications. The vars in the inventory are unique for the groups, i.e each service has it's own lb pool and http port. Also there can be multiple applications on one host. And here is what the playbook likes like:

```
---
- hosts: all
  remote_user: deployment
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  gather_facts: yes
  serial: 1
  roles:
    - app-deploy
```

The tasks in the role simply prints out the variables nginxpool and httpport.

I run the playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i inventory.py --limit componentA-service_ci
```

**Expected result:**

```
TASK [app-deploy : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com] => {
    "msg": "pool componentA_pool port 8100"
}

TASK [app-deploy : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [host2.example.com] => {
    "msg": "pool componentA_pool port 8100"
}
```

**Actual result:**

```
TASK [app-deploy : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [host1.example.com] => {
    "msg": "pool componentB_pool port 9999"
}

TASK [app-deploy : debug] ******************************************************
ok: [host2.example.com] => {
    "msg": "pool componentA_pool port 8100"
}
```

The `--limit` works in that ansible deploys on the hosts that are listed for componentA-service_ci but for host1.example.com I'm getting the value of nginxpool and httpport from componentB-service_ci vars. I read the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html) but fails to understand how this can happen? Is this a bug or am I just not understanding how ansible works here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run ansible on specific hosts group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41500463/run-ansible-on-specific-hosts-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is, ansible builds the complete inventory first and then searches for the plays that match your limits.

Since a host (`host1.example.com`) belongs to two groups that specify the same variable, the information gets mixed up while setting up the inventory. The content of the `httpport` variable of `host1.example.com` could be from the `componentA`-group or from `componentB`-group.

After the inventory is built, ansible tries to limit the plays to those containing hosts from the specified limiting group

Rename your variables so that the variable names are unique and then use the specific variable names within the certain group in plays:

```
{
  "componentA-service_ci": {
    "hosts": [
      "host1.example.com",
      "host2.example.com"
    ],
    "vars": {
      "componentA_httpport": "8100",
      "componentA_nginxpool": "componentA_pool"
    }
  },
  "componentB-service_ci": {
    "hosts": [
      "host1.example.com",
      "host3.example.com"
    ],
    "vars": {
      "componentB_httpport": "9999",
      "componentB_nginxpool": "componentB_pool"
    }
  }
}
```

Now the host `host1.example.com` has four variables `componentA_httpport`, `componentA_nginxpool` and `componentB_httpport`, `componentB_nginxpool`.

Comment: Thx for the insight. I later found this issue at github https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9065
I really think this is a bug, using different variable names isn't going to work as it's a generic playbook, I ended up with a wrapper script doing the lookup before running ansible-playbook and injecting the variables as extra-vars.